# AngularJS two-way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, dom-events

I am having problems with two-way binding in `AngularJS`. In my `HTML`, I have:

```html
<div class="row" ng-app="creation">
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-controller="CreationController as cCtrl" ng-submit="cCtrl.send()" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-4">Model</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" ng-model="cCtrl['data']['model']" id="model" />
            </div>
        </div>
    ...
```

On the `JavaScript` side, I have:

```js
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('creation', ['validation', 'link']);

    app.controller('CreationController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.data.model = 'hello';
    ...
```

Why is `$scope.data.model` not displaying *hello* when I render the `HTML` page? Instead it is displaying nothing, and when I finally entering something in the input field, it updates `$scope.data.model`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're setting your data model on the `$scope` but in your html you're referencing under `cCtrl` which is a controller instance. Try just using `ng-model=data.model` in your html.

Answer (score 0):

Actually that '**Controller as**' syntax can be very useful and easy to follow.
I would prefer to keep that because you can isolate the data as you want and work with it in a cleaner way.

The problem with your code is that you have to bind the **data** object to **this**, not to the **$scope**

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('creation', ['validation', 'link']);

app.controller('CreationController', [function() {
    // You can use an object to refer to *this* (vm stands for 'ViewModel').
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = {};
    vm.data.model = 'hello';
    // or just have vm.data = {model: 'hello'};
...
```

and then use it in the template like you've used it.

More than that you do **not have** to inject the $scope** unless you want to use something specific from angular like digest or watch, or inherit from parent scopes/parent controllers.

Here is also a nice style guide for angular that explains other concepts also: [Angular Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers)